# Expected number of trials before I get one of each type

Tags: probability

Say I have a population that I sample from without replacement. In this population there are $a_1$ members of type 1, $a_2$ members of type two and so forth up to $a_k$ of type $k$.

What is the expected number of trials until I collect at least one member out of each type? An example here would be the expected number of cards drawn from a deck until I get one of every valor.

Comment: See [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) ( although it is 'with replacement' ).

Comment: One can use the method of indicator random variables. We end up with a rather messy sum. I do not know how to simplify it, and do not  have good reason to think the sum can be simplified.

Comment: Essentially no analytic solution for large $k$?

Comment: @Alex  without replacement, if $a_i=1 \forall i$ then the number is $k$ (and no uncertainty)

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I think the sum may be quite pretty, as $1$ plus the sum of  $2^k-2$ simple divisions.

Comment: The sum has a nice *shape*, but I believe does not simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=1$ you clearly have an expectation of $1$.

For $k=2$ you seem to have an expectation of $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{a_1+a_2} \frac{{a_1 \choose n}+{a_2 \choose n} - {0 \choose n}}{{a_1 + a_2 \choose n}}=  1+\dfrac{a_1}{a_2+1}+\dfrac{a_2}{a_1+1}$$ taking ${m \choose n}=0$ when $0 \le m \lt n$

For $k=3$ you seem to have an expectation of $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{a_1+a_2+a_3} \frac{{a_1+a_2 \choose n}+{a_1+a_3 \choose n}+{a_2+a_3 \choose n}-{a_1 \choose n}-{a_2 \choose n}-{a_3 \choose n} + {0 \choose n}}{{a_1 + a_2 +a_3\choose n}} \\=1 + \frac{a_1+a_2}{a_3+1}+\frac{a_1+a_3}{a_2+1}+\frac{a_2+a_3}{a_3+1}-\frac{a_1}{a_2+a_3+1}-\frac{a_2}{a_1+a_3+1}-\frac{a_3}{a_1+a_2+1}$$

and I would expect a similar inclusion-exclusion type calculation to apply for larger $k$.

Comment: For your example of the expected number of cards drawn from a deck until you get one of every value, you have $k=13$ and $a_i=4$, and this gives a result of about $27.997122$

Comment: Although it wasn't the answer I was hoping for, nonetheless it kind of highlights how hopeless some combinatorics problems are. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry, I have been enjoying this problem and I understand the proof, I just don't know how you simplify, the summation, if I could know how this result follows then everything works: $\sum ^{a_{1}+a_{2}}_{n=1}\dfrac {\begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ n \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} a_{1}+a_{2} \\ n \end{pmatrix}}=\dfrac {a_{1}}{1+a_{2}}$

Comment: @Henry, Ok I still can't see it

Comment: I should have said related to  $\sum\limits_{m=0}^b  {c+m \choose c} ={b+c+1 \choose c+1} = \frac{b+c+1}{c+1} {b+c \choose c}$ with the first equality explained by looking at Pascal's triangle and the second adapting the factorials. Then you can say   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{a_1+a_2}  \dfrac{a_1 \choose n}{a_1+a_2 \choose n} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{a_1}  \dfrac{a_1 \choose n}{a_1+a_2 \choose n} - 1$ $= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{a_1}  \dfrac{a_2 +n \choose a_2}{a_1+a_2 \choose a_2} - 1$ $= \dfrac{a_2+a_1+1}{a_2+1}-1$ $= \dfrac{a_1}{a_2+1}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I didn't get the middle step, but asked someboy and they were able to help, Now I understand but have a page of working just to prove $\sum ^{a_{1}+a_{2}}_{n=1}\dfrac {\begin{pmatrix} a_{1} \\ n \end{pmatrix}}{\begin{pmatrix} a_{1}+a_{2} \\ n \end{pmatrix}}=\dfrac {a_{1}}{1+a_{2}}$ Seems quite tricky to simplify, did you realise straight away when solving the problem?

Comment: @Tinatim - it was over two years ago so I do not remember.  I seem to have used the word *seem* so I may or may not have used some shortcuts or an empirical calcuation